# My Openshift app (free plan) keeps disapearing after few days

Tags: openshift-origin

Does anymore same experience or solution for that ?
My app works fine only several days after deployment, after that it turns to blank screen with "Not Found" text on it.
App is with "WildFly Application Server 8.2.1.Final" Cartridge with status "Started" - note that I am aware of iddling of apps at Openshift, this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Recieved reply from OpenShift as following :

It looks like you're hosting your app on a small gear. The WildFly cartridge could be quite memory consuming, depending on what app you are deploying. Please check whether the gear is not having memory issues, as described 
https://developers.openshift.com/faq/troubleshooting.html#_why_is_my_application_restarting_automatically_or_having_memory_issues

If there seems to be no memory issues, please check your log files for further information about the problem. You can check your log files by using the 'rhc tail' command, or by sshing into your application and looking in the ~/app-root/logs directory.
You can learn more about checking your log files in our Developer Portal (https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-log-files.html)